# Can MultiselectList be used in MVVM style(bind its IsSelected property to viewmodel)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I read the example of using MultiselectList in WindowsPhoneGeek
[part1](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-MultiselectList-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API) [part2](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-MultiselectList-in-depth-Part2-Data-Binding)

When I implementing the SelectAll and UnSelectAll function of the MultiselectList, I find that not all the items in MultiselectList were Select/UnSelect properly if the number of items over a certain limit. Some of the items won't go into the if section in following code

```
DependencyObject visualItem = itemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(pizzaOption);
MultiselectItem multiselectItem = visualItem as MultiselectItem;
if (multiselectItem != null)
{
    // NOTE: this will also add an item to the SelectedItems collection
    multiselectItem.IsSelected = selected;
}
```

I guess it's because not all the multiselectItem were shown in UI that time.
But I do need the SelectAll to select all the items in MultiselectList not only the items in UI. WHAT CAN I DO? I've been thinking about binding the IsSelected Property to viewmodel as a workaround, but I tried the following code and got exception when parsing the xaml of that page.

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="toolkit:MultiselectItem">
        <Setter Property="HintPanelHeight" Value="75"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsMarked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
</toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Please help me..
Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

You get a xaml parsing error because your

```
<Style TargetType="toolkit:MultiselectItem">
        <Setter Property="HintPanelHeight" Value="75"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsMarked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>
```

Should be on a resources, let's say

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="toolkit:MultiselectItem">
            <Setter Property="HintPanelHeight" Value="75"/>
    </Style>
</toolkit:MultiselectList.Resources>
```

For me, I would bind the datacontext of the MultiselectList to a class and do a foreach on its items like

```
DataContext = new List<ClassADataContext>();

foreach(var items in DataContext)
{
  ... logic
   items.IsMarked = false; or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But about the xaml parsing, the HintPanelHeight works fine in my code, it only shows exception after adding the <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsMarked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>.
And the binding I am looking for is the binding for "IsSelected" property, I already bind the MultiselectList to my ObservableCollection without problem. =)